# How to get Microsoft Search to index common file types like .pdf and .pub

Tags: windows, pdf, windows-search, microsoft-publisher

I'm trying to get Windows Search (4.0) to index PDFs and .pub, .doc, etc. files.

The files are on an XP Pro PC acting as a file server. But I don't have MS Office, etc. installed (no need, trying to keep it "slim and trim") but WS 4.0 is doing the indexing of those files and not indexing .pdf and .pub.

I've found a few [addons](http://gallery.live.com/default.aspx?pl=6) (from Foxit PDF reader) rated 3/5 and only support WS 2.0 or 3.0. 
Looking for other solutions and also a way to index .pub files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More searching revealed that Foxit has released what seems to be a newer [PDF iFilter for Windows Search](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/ifilter/index.html#downifilter) which has gotten rave reviews and supports up to Windows 7. And not even Copernicus supports .pub files so maybe searching .pub files is a Lost Cause.

Answer (score 0):

It won't index them within the Windows search, but the [everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) search will swiftly conduct a search for a given file type. You can include part of a file name if you like.

[image]